# magento: create a thumbnail image in the csv file

Tags: image, excel, magento, csv

I have a webshop with over 1500 products, with some mistake I made I accidentally deleted the base image, small image and the thumbnail. I still have the original images. I have tried to add the image link to the product in the csv file but this doesnt work.

(I first export the csv then I import the changed csv back)

when I made one product how i wanted it, it showed me this:(third picture)

[image: the exported csv file]

[image: this is the search result]

[image: correct product image]